# Form action isn't triggering at all

Tags: python, html, django, forms

Basically I am currently trying to work around the fact that you have to do a HttpResponseRedirect after form submission to avoid repeat submissions on page refresh.

So I want my submit button for my form to trigger another view, not submit the current view. Here is my html:
(I've taken the form out because there's lots of code to render the table horizontally)

```
<form id= "time-form" method = 'POST' action='' class="dynamic-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
            <div id="formset-container" class = "formset-container">
                <table>
                <--form is in here-->
                </table>
                <ul>{{ newtime_formset.errors }}</ul>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div>   
                <input type = "submit" id = "save" action="{% url 'tande:create_time' %}" value = "Save Timesheet">
            </div>
```

So I want the submit button to execute the create_time view. We are currently in a view called timesheet. But it's not entering the create_time view at all it just stays in the current view.

```
def create_time(request):
    #below isn't printing
    print "create_time view"
    #save the form in here
    return HttpResponseRedirect('timesheet')
```

And the url for both view:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<timesheet_id>[0-9]+)/person/timesheet/$', views.timesheet, name='timesheet' ),
    url(r'^create_time/$', views.create_time, name='create_time' ),  
]
```

So I want to save the timesheet in create_time and then go back to timesheet to avoid redirecting.... I think that makes sense.... :S

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

action parameter in form defines where the pages does a submit not the button.

```
<form id= "time-form" method = 'POST' action="{% url 'tande:create_time' %}" class="dynamic-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
     <div id="formset-container" class = "formset-container">
          <table>
             <--form is in here-->
          </table>
          <ul>{{ newtime_formset.errors }}</ul>
      </div>
      </br>
      <div>   
          <input type = "submit" id = "save" value = "Save Timesheet">
   </div>
</form>
```

Also in your view you will need to django reverse url resolver

```
def create_time(request):
    #below isn't printing
    print "create_time view"
    #save the form in here
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('timesheet', kwargs={"timesheet_id":<timesheet_id>}))
```

Comment: One more problem, I get timesheet_id global name is not defined. So I tried `kwargs={"timesheet_id": timesheet_object}` which is the id value and get NoReverseMatch....
**Reverse for 'timesheet' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'timesheet_id': u'34'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []**

Comment: That is a convention , you need to replace it with a variable containing the timesheet id. Should be id of the object that you created in the form post generally

Comment: Oh I see! in the above '34' is my timesheet id... I need that in the url..

Comment: Ah, I solved it by putting "tande:timesheet". It may be to do with the fact I have a variable named timesheet earlier in the view...